# CSS Styles Not Properly Applied to Dynamically Added List Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue for a few hours.

I have a list that I'm dynamically adding items to using JavaScript & the Dojo library. I've done it using both vanilla JS and Dojo, so I've ruled that part out.

The issue: When the new list items are appended to the current list, they lack some of the CSS styles the other elements have. Not all of them, but things like 'white-space: nowrap' and margins are off.

Code can be view here: http://jsbin.com/omEJoBAf/2/

Screenshot of it in my application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQbC4.jpg

Comment: Can you possibly illustrate the problem with a screenshot? I'm seeing all of the same classes and styles applied when I try your demo and click on "Add Filter".

Comment: Are you saying the second `row` of items is not `wrapping` as expected? Cause `margins` look fine... what browser?

Comment: I added a screenshot. It's in all browsers. It seems to have something to do with the wrapping, but the list elements previously added wrap just fine, the dynamically added ones are the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your css values are the same accross objects. As far as what I think your problem is, it has to do with the fact that your elements are all 'inline'. There are line-breaks in the code that are getting rendered as spaces, but dynamically added elements are added on the same line so there's no space.

Couple things you could do. Probably the fix I would use is to set the li elements to 'display:block; float:left'. You could also remove the linebreaks in the code for all the li elements that are initially rendered on the page.

EDIT: After seeing your screen cap, I'm positive its because they're inline. Float em, or remove line-breaks will fix it.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Second set of eyes always helps, haha!